# Duplicate book is being added in cart and book is not being incremented as I add book in cart. Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, shopping-cart

I am building a basic bookstore application in Angular 2 using typescript. `selectedBook(b: Books)` is a method in my **BookComponent**.

- When the program runs, list of books are shown in table and each book
  has it own **"Add to cart" button**.
- **On click of Add to cart button** `selectedBook(b: Books)` method is called & the selected book is passed to the method as parameter.
- Further the method should add the book to `cartArray` variable(is array of
  Books model), if its a duplicate book it should not add the book.
- While clicking **Add to cart**, as the duplicate bookQuantity
  decrements from book table view, it should increment in the `cartArray` (I
  have not written code for this as idk where to start from) .

books.model :

```
   export interface Books {
         id: number,
         bookId: string,
         bookName: string,
         bookQuantity: number,
         bookPrice: string,
         bookAuthor: string,
         bookPublished: string
}
```

Working within `selectedBook(b: Books)` method (but its not working as I expect) :

1. When `selectedBook(b: Books)` is called for the first time it decrements the selected book quantity and adds it to the cart.
2. Next time when the method is called it iterates through the elements
   in cart and checks if the book with the same `bookId` is present or
   not, if present it set boolean variable `duplicateBook` to `true` else
   `false`. If `duplicateBook` is `false` add the book to `cartArray`.
3. Finally I store the `cartArray` onto localstorage.

BookComponent :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {Books} from '../models/books.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'book',
    templateUrl: `
     <table class="table table-hover">           
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Publisher</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="#b of books">
          <td><a>{{ b.bookId }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ b.bookName }}</td>
          <td>{{ b.bookQuantity }}</td>
          <td>{{ b.bookPrice }}</td>
          <td>{{ b.bookAuthor }}</td>
          <td>{{ b.bookPublished }}</td>
          <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="b.bookQuantity > 0" (click)="selectedBook(b)">Add to cart</button>
              <div *ngIf="b.bookQuantity < 1">Out of stock</div>
          </td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
`
})
export class BooksComponent {

    books: Books[] = [
        { id: 1, bookId: '1', bookName: 'C', bookQuantity: 7, bookPrice: '2345', bookAuthor: 'fsdf', bookPublished: 'edsdf' },
        { id: 2, bookId: '2', bookName: 'Java', bookQuantity: 52, bookPrice: '3242', bookAuthor: 'sdfs', bookPublished: 'fghzxdffv' },
        { id: 3, bookId: '3', bookName: 'SQL', bookQuantity: 7, bookPrice: '5645', bookAuthor: 'dfghrty', bookPublished: 'ghjghj' }
    ];
    cart: Books[] = [];
    duplicateBook: boolean = false;

    selectedBook(b: Books) 
    {

        b.bookQuantity = b.bookQuantity - 1;

        if (this.cart.length == 0) {
            //b.bookQuantity = 1;
            this.cart.push(b);
        }
        else {
            for (let e of this.cart) {
                console.log(e.bookId, "==", b.bookId);
                if (e.bookId == b.bookId) {
                    console.log("Book is in cart");
                    this.duplicateBook = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!this.duplicateBook) {
                //increment previously added book quantity in cart by 1
                this.cart.push(b);
            }
        }
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(this.cart));

        console.log("Cart contents are : ", this.cart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see all the code of the component. It's hard to tell without it but I believe that `books` from this line in the template

```
<tr *ngFor="#b of books">
```

is pointing at a copy of books instead of pointing at the actual object from the service.